# Capacitor discharge problem in long button press action

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, analog

I am trying to perform switching based on long press (ignore short presses). I found some circuits online but one way or another, they all use capcitor to provide delay. For example, [image]

If anyone have more efficient circuit, please share.

My main concern is capacitor takes time to charge and discharge as well so if I keep pressing the button continuously for short time again and again, it will still charge the capacitor and I want to ignore that. Even once charged after long press, second instant press will trigger the signal because capacitor was already charged before. How can I discharge this capacitor instantaneously (faster than charging) in the same circuit?

Note : I want to perform this using only one button.

Comment: It is unclear how you want the circuit to work with long presses. Turn the LEDs on after long press only? Also as it is drawn now, the button will disconnect the power supply from whole circuit, and it will damage the LEDs since nothing limits current.

Comment: Sorry for unclearity. Yes, I want to trigger output only on long press. I have another circuit that toggle the output on every signal (one long press on, next long press off). That circuit will further going to switch another 20A supply. Example shown above is just provided by someone online so I copied but all I want is signal, be it high to low or low to high on long press only.

Comment: You can't do any of this without more details on V, I, DCR C max. Basically you are using a supercap as a tiny rechargeable battery. Battery chargers and control switches are common but you want a SPDT switch using dual FETs with a programmable battery charger IC with CC, CV and maybe a timer clock

Comment: Please ignore supply cut off and led current issue. I have tried this circuit with modification and it is working just the issue I have mentioned in quetion is still there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use a push-to-break switch, the solution is trivial:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPhbvp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here, the switch keeps capacitor Ct discharged, and only allows it to charge (slowly via Rt) when the switch is opened by pressing it. To protect the switch from huge currents that would flow, and arcing, if were to discharge the capacitor directly, we limit current with R1.

With the switch open, capacitor Ct is allowed to charge via Rt, with a time constant of \$R_tC_t\$, which is 1s using the values shown. When capacitor potential is applied to a standard logic input (which ideally should be a schmitt trigger) to "sense" the signal, this would correspond to about this same delay before OUT goes high.

Closing SW1, though, discharges the capacitor very quickly via R1 (in 1ms or so, using the shown values), and it stays discharged until the switch opens again.

Since it's likely that you don't have push-to-break switches handy, this next approach uses the switches' open state to turn on a transistor, to create that low impedance discharge path:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAOJaw.png)</sup>

When switch SW1 is closed, Q1's gate is pulled low, and Q1 is off. Ct is then permitted to slowly charge via Rt. When SW1 is open, transistor Q1's gate is held high by R1, the transistor's channel resistance drops to a couple of ohms, and the capacitor is quickly discharged via R2.

If you wish to have an output signal that goes low after some time, you can place Ct high-side, and use a P-channel MOSFET instead. You could even use bipolar transistors, if that's all you have:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1AslS.png)</sup>

You may notice R3 is significantly smaller than R1; that's because a bipolar junction transistor requires base current to pass sufficient collector current to discharge Ct2 quickly, base current which flows more or less permanently. For this reason I recommend using a MOSFET.

Comment: Circuit mentioned by you seems working. I will try rest to match logic level I am looking for.  Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHSunk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Take two] with a single toggle switch and a D FF (edge triggered clock is delayed "with TBD long press")
The resistors can all be scaled up x10 for long press time. these values are approximately 1/3 second for long press.  Although you do not need a long press as this is a latch so the 470k can be bypassed.